# Как выйти из observer LiveData если получил нужные данные?

Tags: java, android, rxjava, observer

```
    mViewModel.getShopProducts(mBinding.get().getShop(), limit, offset)
            .observe(this, observer -> {
                if (observer != null) {
                    mAdapter.get().add(observer.data, isUpdate);
                }
            });
```